# I deleted a review in play store by mistake. How do i recover it?

Tags: google-play-store

I deleted a review in  google play store by mistake. How do i recover it?

Answer (score 0):

I have deleted many reviews myself and have from time to time deleted a wrong one... there's no way to directly recover it but if you're quick enough and own a different android device, on a different email account, you can find the review and take a screenshot of it before the deletion request is processed.

I wouldn't exactly call that "recovering" but it's an option